# Getting error while importing primeng scroll panel in angular 4

Tags: angular, primeng

I am working on Angular 4 and i want to use PrimeNG scroll panel. I am using primeng 4.0. But when importing primeng scroll panel i am getting "Cannot find module" error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You should post your code. Where does the error occur ?

Comment: Did you install primeng via npm? Do you use Angular CLI?

Comment: Yes, I did use npm and angular CLI.

Comment: Then it should work. Can you reproduce the problem in a new project? If yes, can you share the newly written code?

Comment: How you imported it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ScrollPanel was added to PrimeNg release 5.1. Try updating your PrimeNg

```
npm install primeng@latest
```

See this github entry for the new ScrollPanel component:

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3917

[image]